# AVCaptureDevice DiscoverySession for iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm developing a QR and Matrix Code reader app. I'm getting `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with `AvCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession`. My problem is that It is only available after iOS 10.0. How can I get it for fallback versions?

```
// Get the back-facing camera for capturing videos
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
    guard let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first else {
        print("Failed to get the camera device")
        return
    }

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
do {
    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

    // Set the input device on the capture session.
    captureSession.addInput(input)

    // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
    let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    captureSession.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

    // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
    captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    //TODO: Decide the data types!
    captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.dataMatrix]
    //captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

} catch {
    // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
    print(error)
    return
}
```

Comment: If you're developing a new app, you really don't want to be supporting back to iOS 9 if you can help it. In a couple of weeks you'll have to support 4 versions (9-12)

Comment: Sorry, I must support iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of `AVCaptureDevice`, you can use

```
let cameras = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)
```

in `iOS 9`

Comment: does not find front camera